# Proof: A set $\Omega$ is closed if its complement $\Omega^c = \mathbb{C} - \Omega$ is open.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove the following theorem in the context of complex analysis:

> A set $\Omega$ is closed if its complement $\Omega^c = \mathbb{C} - \Omega$ is open.

Preceding this theorem, the textbook does define open/closed sets and interior points, but **it is only after this theorem that the textbook defines limit points**. Therefore, I'm guessing that this should be provable without limit points (using the information conveyed up till this point in the textbook). The textbook later gives an equivalent theorem in terms of limit points, and I will attempt to prove this one later.

My proof proceeds as follows:

We begin by assuming that $\Omega^c = \mathbb{C} - \Omega = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : z \not\in \Omega \}$ is an open set.

A set is open if every point in that set is an interior point. Therefore, if $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$, there exists $r > 0$ such that

$$D_r (z_0) = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z - z_0| < r \} = \Omega^c$$

This is the open set.

Now here's where I get confused.

Next, I take the complement of the set $\Omega^c$. As I understand it, the complement is the negation, and so when we take the complement of a set, we take the negation of the set condition:

$$(\Omega^c)^c = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z - z_0| \ge r \} = \Omega$$

This should be a closed set, but it isn't. A closed set is defined as

$$\bar{D}_r (z_0) = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z - z_0| \le 0 \}$$

But the negation of $<$ is $\ge$, which is why I have $\Omega = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z - z_0| \ge r \}$

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please tell me what I'm misunderstanding and how this should be done.

EDIT:

The closed disc $\bar{D}_r(z_0)$ of radius $r$ centred at $z_0$ is defined by

$$\bar{D}_r(z_0) = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z - z_0| \le r \}$$

and the boundary of either the open or closed disc is the circle

$$C_r(z_0) = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z - z_0| = r \}$$

Given a set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$, a point $z_0$ is an interior point of $\Omega$ if there exists $r > 0$ such that

$$D_r(z_0) \subset \Omega$$

Finally, a set $\Omega$ is open if every point in that set is an interior point of $\Omega$.

Comment: An open set does not have to be an open ball nor does a closed set have to be a closed ball.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Ahh, yes, that makes sense. The open/closed discs section was immediately preceding the theorem in the textbook, so I must have just assumed that this is how to proceed. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I think you should provide the definition of "closed set" you are using. After all, there are many equivalent definitions one can use in the context, including the one about limit points.

Comment: @JWL I have made an edit.

Comment: @ThePointer Yes but you didn't include the definition of "closed set".

Comment: @JWL Sorry, I just realised that the textbook defines an **open** set, but it does not define a closed set in any other way than what it says in the theorem (that I'm trying to prove). So the only time it mentions **closed** sets is in the following theorem: A set $\Omega$ is closed if its complement $\Omega^c = \mathbb{C} - \Omega$ is open.

Comment: If there is no definition of closed sets, the exercise is pointless and there is nothing to prove.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes, I thought something seemed unusual about trying to prove the theorem in this way. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: You could (and maybe should) take it as the definition: a closed set is the complement of an open set.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes, that's exactly what I'm doing now. In fact, I think that is the way that the author intended it to be. Unfortunately, I think it was just written in a way that could cause confusion, hence the reason for this thread.

Answer (score 1):

You want $D_r(z_0)\color{blue}{\subseteq}\Omega^c$.

I think you went off track after that.

How bout the fact that each $z_0\in\Omega^c$ having an open set containing it which is disjoint from $\Omega$ implies that $z_0$ is not in the frontier* of $\Omega$.  Thus all of $\Omega$'s frontier points are in $\Omega$.  Thus $\Omega$ is closed.

*frontier of $X$ is defined as the intersection of the closure of $X$ and the closure of $X^c$.

Alternatively,  consider that $D_r(z_0)^c$ is closed and contains $\Omega$.  Thus $z_0\not\in\bar\Omega$. The closure is the smallest closed set containing $\Omega$. Thus $\bar\Omega\subset(\Omega^c)^c=\Omega$.

This second way seems more like what you were trying to do.

Comment: OP did not want a proof with that limit point thingy.

Comment: I overlooked that.  Maybe I'll try another way.  @WilliamElliot

Comment: Hi Chris. @WilliamElliot is correct. However, I wonder if the theorem was inserted in a chronologically incorrect order by the author? Immediately after, the author introduces **limit points**, and then gives the theorem "*A set is closed if and only if it contains all its limit points.*" Maybe there is no clear way to prove the first theorem, and it must instead be proved in the second way using limit points?

Comment: What about my edit?  That might be a way.  Did you have the _closure_ yet?

Comment: Unfortunately, closure comes later as well. What exactly is $D_r(z_0)^c$? Would it be $\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z - z_0| \ge r \}$ as I've written?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: Based on @HennoBrandsma's comment on the main post, I think the author has indeed made a chronological error.

Comment: Well, yes, they seem to have gotten to the bottom of this:  we need the $\bf{definition}$.  At one point I guessed that maybe you had that discs are open and their complements closed.  But that's just a wild guess.  What book is it?

Comment: @ChrisCuster *Complex Analysis* by Stein and Shakarchi.

Comment: On page $6$, they give the _definition_ that a set $\Omega$ is closed if its complement is open.  So what you're calling a theorem is actually a definition.   This is the most common definition btw.